# Get message from pubnub received JSON

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, pubnub

[Received JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GceE.png)

I want to get the value of the object "Message", the numbers in this example. 
This is what i already have:

```
pubnub.addListener({
    status: function(statusEvent) {
        console.log(statusEvent);

    },
    message: function(message) {
        console.log("New Message!!", message);
        var mesg = message.getValueof(message.message());
        console.log(mesg);



    },
```

Comment: Forgot to say the var mesg... doesnt work obviously

Comment: cant we achive with message.message??

Comment: Yeah......... I use webstorm, and it said it won't work but when i test it for real it does work, thanks

Comment: omg i just throw a stone into dark.....

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `message.message` to fetch from your json